# Move ext2 boot partition to LVM

Tags: boot, lvm, boot-partition

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 server with an ext2 boot partition and an LVM setup.

I want to move or copy the boot partition content to be within the LVM.

I have searched and the closest thing I found was this https://www.system-rescue.org/lvm-guide-en/Moving-the-linux-rootfs-to-an-LVM-volume/

I am unsure how to edit the grub boot menu after copying the boot content to the /boot folder in the LVM.

Comment: Reminder: Standard (Community) Support for Ubuntu 16.04 ends in two weeks. If you have a question or problem in three weeks, we won't answer it anymore.

Comment: Just a reminder 16.04 reaches end of standard support on April 22 2021 so you may want to think about upgrading to 18.04 or 20.04. End of Stand Support means no more support or updates. You may not ask questions here either as 16.04 will be off topic. If you sign up for ESM you can still get security patches but that is all.

Answer (score 0):

GRUB (when configured correctly) will give you a passphrase prompt used to unlock the second-stage boot loader. [The last few steps **here** show you how to do this.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Full_Disk_Encryption_Howto_2019)

I suggest copying everything off and doing this, and then restoring needed files from backup.